# Return conditional rendering in React doesn't show Fetch elemets

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey guys thanks for your time. I'm still new to React so I'm trying to learn how to use it. I'm retrieving items from an API and after I'm getting a success, I push the  setState to create the new components from the response - and I don't have any problems with that.
But I was trying to render two different components, one for the loading state when we are waiting for a response from the server, and the actual elements. And I know there is a way to do it with a ternary condition. But I think an anonymous function looks better. And this works well with the "Loading..." state, but after I get the response from the server, it doesn't display anything. If I'll throw even static data there - it doesn't show. How this thing works like? Cause If I'll debug each element in map - I'll have my response - but It just don't want to render them.

```
export function Main(){

  const [state, setState] = useState({users: []});
  const temporaryUsers = state.users;
  useEffect(() => {
      fetch(`https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => {
        temporaryUsers.push(json);
        setState({
          users: temporaryUsers
        });
      });
        
    },[])
  
      return(
        <>
          {(() => {
            if (state.users[0] != undefined){
              state.users[0].results.map((elem) => {
                return(
                  <User  props={elem} />
                )
              })
              
            } else{
              return (
                <p style={{textAlign:"center", display:"block", width:"100%"}}>Loading...</p>
              ) 
            }
          })()}
        </>
        
      )
  
}
```

Comment: FYI, using an anonymous [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) in your render code is not typical React practice. IMO, it encourages too much logic to be put into the render code. I would argue that if you find yourself wanting to use an anonymous function like that, it is a sign that you might want to create a separate component for that logic instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**
Implemented it in react playground [here](https://playcode.io/1487504) using static data with delay.

---

Instead of directly modifying the temporaryUsers array and pushing the response, you should create a new array with the response data and then update the state using that new array.

```
export function Main() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ users: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://randomuser.me/api/?results=20")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setState({ users: json.results });
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {state.users.length > 0 ? (
        state.users.map((elem) => <User key={elem.id} props={elem} />)
      ) : (
        <p style={{ textAlign: "center", display: "block", width: "100%" }}>
          Loading...
        </p>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm pushing another variable, cause I can't get how to add new elements + previous elements.
Something like that, but not sure:
setState({
            users: [...state.users , json.response]
          });

Comment: Yes, the spread operator ([...state.users , json.response]) should work for that. Also, if the effect depends on a state variable it should be added to the dependency list is the useEffect.

Comment: @Ahmar I don't think adding the state variable to the dependency array would be helpful in this case, as it would cause the effect to be re-run over and over again, as the list of users changes after each fetch call. That would not be the desired behavior, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

The map loop should be:

```
state.users[0].results.map((elem) =>(
              <User  props={elem} />
            ))
```

Comment: Still nothing with that

Comment: can you use console.log to print the return data in the console, and then post the result in this post?

Answer (score 0):

The return block should be

```
  <>
{ state.users[0]?.length===0
    ? <p>...loading</p> 
    : state.users[0]?.results.map((item,key)=><User{...item} key={key}/>)
}
</>
```

And your User component

```
    export const User = (props) => {
      return (
        <div>{props.gender}</div>
      )

}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).